# Pre-install code

Tags: cmake

Is there any analogy

```
install(CODE ...) # this code is executing AFTER install step
```

for pre-install step in cmake?

I suppose code execution in POST_BUILD step, but how to run this code?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Actually, `install(CODE)` and `install(SCRIPT)` are executed in the order in which they appear among other `install()` commands, so if your call to `install(CODE)` is the first `install()` call, it will be executed before all other installation commands.

Note that the ordering mentioned above (`install()` commands executed in order of appearance) applies for commands within one install component and one CMakeList file (thanks to [@John](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2414411/john) for pointing this out in comments) . Nevertheless, for the intended "pre-install" step, putting the command on the first place in the first CMakeList should still work.

Comment: This is not true, if the install commands are for different components. Then they will be executed in alphabetical order of the component names. It is also not true for install commands, which are for the same component, but in different cmake files. In this case the install commands in sub-directory cmake files are executed afterwards.